# Set values in repeating table fields programmatically

Tags: development, infopath

I have some logic which calculated a list of dates that are to be displayed in the repeating table. The repeating table structure is as shown in the image:

[image]

The code that I have used to set data in the repeating table is as follows:

```
      string myNamespace = NamespaceManager.LookupNamespace("my");
      using (XmlWriter writer = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("my:myFields/my:SecPM", NamespaceManager).AppendChild())
      {
          writer.WriteStartElement("RepTablePMDates", NamespaceManager.ToString());
          writer.WriteElementString("PMDate", NamespaceManager.ToString(), endDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
          writer.WriteEndElement();
          writer.Close();
      }
```

Please guide

Comment: Can you please try to clarify your question, it is hard to tell what you are really asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mancy,

Please try second method describe here:
[4 Ways to programmatically add a row to a repeating table in InfoPath](http://www.bizsupportonline.net/infopath2007/4-way-programmatically-add-row-repeating-table.htm)

> **Method 2 - Use an XPathNavigator object to add a row to a repeating table in InfoPath**
>
> In the following sample code an XmlDocument is used to construct the
>   XML for a row and then an XPathNavigator object is created from the
>   document element of this XmlDocument and passed to the AppendChild
>   method to add a row to a repeating table in InfoPath.
>
> ```
> XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
> XmlNode group = doc.CreateElement("group2", NamespaceManager.LookupNamespace("my"));
>
> XmlNode field = doc.CreateElement("field1", NamespaceManager.LookupNamespace("my"));
> XmlNode node = group.AppendChild(field);
> node.InnerText = "Cell 1";
>
> field = doc.CreateElement("field2", NamespaceManager.LookupNamespace("my"));
> node = group.AppendChild(field);
> node.InnerText = "Cell 2";
>
> field = doc.CreateElement("field3", NamespaceManager.LookupNamespace("my"));
> node = group.AppendChild(field);
> node.InnerText = "Cell 3";
>
> doc.AppendChild(group);
>
> MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode(
>   "/my:myFields/my:group1",
>   NamespaceManager).AppendChild(doc.DocumentElement.CreateNavigator());
> ```

Comment: I used the same link to resolve the problem.